# Bai-Perron method to detect break in constant and trend in regression?

Tags: time-series, cointegration, structural-change

Is it valid to use the Bai-Perron method to detect breaks in the constant and and the trend in a regression, and to use the break dates for cointegration with structural break?

Comment: What happened to your previous user account? Looks like you got yourself a new one.

Comment: As far as I remember, the model for Bai-Perron needs to be stationary (apart from the tested breaks). This would rule out subsequent cointegration analysis. There are also methods for directly addressing cointegration with trend breaks.

Comment: @LarsAhnland, if you still have access to your other account, what do you think of my answers to your questions [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/214593/is-arch-test-mandatory-for-var) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/215459/can-a-cointegrated-variable-be-exogenous-in-first-difference-in-a-vec-model)?